# Find for a start hex string, save the hex string after that to a new file (Python)

Tags: python, file, search, hex, line

I would like to open a text file, search for a hex pattern that starts with 45 3F, grab the following six hex digits, for example `45 4F 5D` and put all the matched digits in a new file. I also know that it always ends with 00 00.

So, given an input file like:

```
bla bla sdsfsdf 45 3F 08 DF 5D 00 00 dsafasdfsadf 45 3F 07 D3 5F 00 00 xztert
```

The result should be:

```
08 DF 5D 07 D3 5F
```

How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
with open('file.txt') as reader:
    my_data = reader.read()

matches = re.findall(r"45 3F ([0-9A-F]{2} [0-9A-F]{2} [0-9A-F]{2})", my_data)
data_to_write = " ".join(matches)
with open('out.txt', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write(data_to_write)
```

but it only prints `[]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I have tried \[code\] but \[it doesn't show any matches\]" Well, are you sure the file actually contains any matching text? Did you try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code? What *exactly* is your understanding of why you get the result that you do? Please note that [you are expected to try to do some research and problem-solving before asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Please also note the edits I have made to your question. This is not a discussion forum and we don't want questions to be "tagged" with text (outside of the actual tag functionality), or decorated with greetings and signoffs.

Comment: answer updated check again !

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def listToString(s):
    str1 = ""
    for ele in s:
        str1 += str(ele)
    return str1

with open('a.txt') as reader:
    for i in reader:
        i = i.strip()
        #r1 = re.findall(r"^\w+", xx)
        r1 = re.findall(r'45 3F(.*?)00', i)
        print(listToString(r1))
        open('out.txt', 'a+').write(listToString(r1) + '\n')
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551. Don't use an image just to show console output from your IDE; copy and paste the output, formatted as code, and explain it as such. You should also *write an answer*,  don't just provide code. Explain what went wrong with OP's approach, explain how your approach works, etc. Finally, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example; this also applies to answers. If your answer depends on a file, show the exact contents, and note any assumptions you are making about the format.

Comment: solid copy ! thanks